# "Locator" positions are wrong/on the wrong plot

Tags: manipulate, programming, dynamic

I have implemented a simple climate model for my students to play around with in Mathematica.  There is a multi-panel plot; the first has CO2 emissions, and you can drag the line around to set up whatever emissions scenario you care to.  The second shows the resulting atmospheric CO2 abundance.  Finally, there's a panel that shows the temperature trajectory.

This worked fine in Mathematica 10, but (I think) 11 broke it.  Now I can't drag the emissions line around — it seems to think the symbols are in another panel.

Here's some code so you can reproduce the problem.  First, here is a 2-panel example that works well:

```
Manipulate[
 lx1 = Sort[lx1, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]; 
 If[lx1[[1]][[1]] < 2015, lx1[[1]][[1]] = 2015];
 f = Interpolation[Join[{{2000, 7}, {2010, 11}}, lx1, {{2500, 0}}]];
 co2x = NDSolve[{c'[t] == f[t]/3. - c[t]/300., c[2010] == 390.}, 
   c, {t, 2000, 2100}];
 tempx = NDSolve[{35 T'[t] == -30.07 + 5.337 Log[c[t]] - 1.749 + 
       0.5 - 3.7/sens T[t] /. co2x, T[2000] == 0.}, 
   T, {t, 2000, 2100}];
 Grid[
  {
   {
    Show[Plot[fi[x], {x, 2000, 2100}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
       ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic], ListPlot[lx1, Joined -> True], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"year", "CO2 emissions (GtC/yr)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]],
Plot[c[x] /. co2x, {x, 2000, 2100}, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], 
 PlotRange -> {250, 900}, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"year", "CO2 abundance (ppm)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]]
},
   {}
   }], {{lx1, Table[{i, fi[i]}, {i, 2020, 2100, 10}]}, 
  Locator}, {{sens, 3, "sensitivity"}, 1.5, 
  4.5}, {{targ, 2, "climate target"}, 1, 3}, 
 Initialization :> (lx = {{2000, 7}, {2010, 11}, {2020, 14}, {2030, 
      16}, {2040, 20}, {2050, 24}, {2060, 25}, {2070, 26}, {2080, 
      27}, {2090, 26}, {2100, 25}}; 
   fi[t1_] := Fit[lx, {1, t, t^2}, t] /. t -> t1), 
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

When I add a panel showing the resulting temperature, things break:

```
Manipulate[
 lx1 = Sort[lx1, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]; 
 If[lx1[[1]][[1]] < 2015, lx1[[1]][[1]] = 2015];
 f = Interpolation[Join[{{2000, 7}, {2010, 11}}, lx1, {{2500, 0}}]];
 co2x = NDSolve[{c'[t] == f[t]/3. - c[t]/300., c[2010] == 390.}, 
   c, {t, 2000, 2100}];
 tempx = NDSolve[{35 T'[t] == -30.07 + 5.337 Log[c[t]] - 1.749 + 
       0.5 - 3.7/sens T[t] /. co2x, T[2000] == 0.}, 
   T, {t, 2000, 2100}];
 Grid[
  {
   {
    Show[Plot[fi[x], {x, 2000, 2100}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
      ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic], ListPlot[lx1, Joined -> True], 
     Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"year", "CO2 emissions (GtC/yr)"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]],
   Plot[c[x] /. co2x, {x, 2000, 2100}, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], 
     PlotRange -> {250, 900}, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"year", "CO2 abundance (ppm)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]]
},
   {Show[Plot[T[x] + 0.8 /. tempx, {x, 2000, 2100}, 
  ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic], 
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{{2000, targ}, {2100, targ}}]}], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"year", "Temperature anomaly (\[Degree]C)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]], Graphics[{
  Text[
   Style[Column[{Row[{"Sensitivity = " , NumberForm[sens, {4, 1}],
         "\[Degree]C"}],

      Row[{"T in 2100 = " , 
        NumberForm[T[2100] + 0.8 /. tempx[[1]], {4, 1}], 
        "\[Degree]C"}],

      Row[{"Total emissions = " , 
        NumberForm[500 + NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 2014, 2100}], {4}], 
        "GtC"}]}], FontSize -> 14], Scaled[{0.2, 1.2}]]
  }]}
  }], {{lx1, Table[{i, fi[i]}, {i, 2020, 2100, 10}]}, 
  Locator}, {{sens, 3, "sensitivity"}, 1.5, 
  4.5}, {{targ, 2, "climate target"}, 1, 3}, 
 Initialization :> (lx = {{2000, 7}, {2010, 11}, {2020, 14}, {2030, 
      16}, {2040, 20}, {2050, 24}, {2060, 25}, {2070, 26}, {2080, 
      27}, {2090, 26}, {2100, 25}}; 
   fi[t1_] := Fit[lx, {1, t, t^2}, t] /. t -> t1), 
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

Note that the code doesn't put the locator symbols on the line, and when I try to drag the line the symbols appear on the bottom panel.  And the line doesn't move right.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't focus too much now but it looks like at least very closely related problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135587/5478

Comment: This question,with an answer, seems similar.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140089/assign-locator-points-to-a-specific-plot?noredirect=1#comment378284_140089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LocatorPane[Dynamic@lx1, ...] and setting the ControlType->None for lx1 seems to work. This answer is derived from the comments in [Assign Locator points to a specific plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140089/assign-locator-points-to-a-specific-plot?noredirect=1#comment378284_140089)

---

```
Manipulate[lx1 = Sort[lx1, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &];
 If[lx1[[1]][[1]] < 2015, lx1[[1]][[1]] = 2015];
 f = Interpolation[Join[{{2000, 7}, {2010, 11}}, lx1, {{2500, 0}}]];
 co2x = NDSolve[{c'[t] == f[t]/3. - c[t]/300., c[2010] == 390.}, 
   c, {t, 2000, 2100}];
 tempx = NDSolve[{35 T'[t] == -30.07 + 5.337 Log[c[t]] - 1.749 + 
       0.5 - 3.7/sens T[t] /. co2x, T[2000] == 0.}, 
   T, {t, 2000, 2100}];
 p1 = Plot[fi[x], {x, 2000, 2100}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], PlotRange -> {0, 30}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic];
 p2 = ListPlot[lx1, Joined -> True, 
   Epilog -> {Dynamic@Locator@Dynamic@lx1}];
 p12 = Show[p1, p2, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"year", "CO2 emissions (GtC/yr)"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]];
 p3 = Plot[c[x] /. co2x, {x, 2000, 2100}, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], 
   PlotRange -> {250, 900}, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"year", "CO2 abundance (ppm)"}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]];
 Grid[{{LocatorPane[Dynamic@lx1, p12, ContinuousAction -> False], 
    p3}, {Show[
     Plot[T[x] + 0.8 /. tempx, {x, 2000, 2100}, 
      ImageSize -> Scaled[0.45], PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic], 
     Graphics[{Red, Line[{{2000, targ}, {2100, targ}}]}], 
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {"year", "Temperature anomaly (\[Degree]C)"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium]], 
    Graphics[{Text[
       Style[Column[{Row[{"Sensitivity = ", NumberForm[sens, {4, 1}], 
            "\[Degree]C"}], 
          Row[{"T in 2100 = ", 
            NumberForm[T[2100] + 0.8 /. tempx[[1]], {4, 1}], 
            "\[Degree]C"}], 
          Row[{"Total emissions = ", 
            NumberForm[500 + NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 2014, 2100}], {4}], 
            "GtC"}]}], FontSize -> 14]
       , Scaled[{0.2, 1.2}]]}]}}]
 , {{lx1, Table[{i, fi[i]}, {i, 2020, 2100, 10}]}, ControlType -> None}
 , {{sens, 3, "sensitivity"}, 1.5, 4.5}
 , {{targ, 2, "climate target"}, 1, 3}, 
 Initialization :> (lx = {{2000, 7}, {2010, 11}, {2020, 14}, {2030, 
      16}, {2040, 20}, {2050, 24}, {2060, 25}, {2070, 26}, {2080, 
      27}, {2090, 26}, {2100, 25}};
   fi[t1_] := Fit[lx, {1, t, t^2}, t] /. t -> t1), 
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

---